# sqlalchemy.execute : name 'ProgrammingError' is not defined

Tags: dataframe, sqlalchemy, execute

I'm trying to update a table

```
res=df.to_dict('records')
table=Table.__table__
stmt = table.update().where(table.c.id == bindparam('_id'))
            
            
exe_res=engine.execute(stmt, res)
```

When I try to run the above code, I'm getting the below error

```
[2022-01-21 06:02:23,190 - ERROR -  - 451722] - name 'ProgrammingError' is not defined
```